# email link not redirecting to play store if app not exists android

Tags: php, android, deep-linking

In android mobile it shows open with the domain/app which i already installed.but if the app is not there it is not redirecting to play store. can anyone help on this. the link is like  http://www.example.com/message

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/message" />
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: kindly check @ Sadiq Md Asif

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior.

If you want to redirect to the Play Store when the app is not installed, you need to build a system to do that. Chrome intents can partially handle this, but only in Chrome. You need something like Firebase Dynamic Links or [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


function launchAndroidApp(url) {
     //var appleAppStoreLink = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=PACKAGEID';
     var appleAppStoreLink =  'market://details?id=PACKAGEID'
     var now = new Date().valueOf();
     setTimeout(function () {
          //if (new Date().valueOf() - now > 500) return;
          window.location = appleAppStoreLink;
     }, 200);
     window.location = url;
}

function launchiOSApp(url) {
     var appleAppStoreLink = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/MY-APP/APPID';
     var now = new Date().valueOf();
     setTimeout(function () {
          if (new Date().valueOf() - now > 500) return;
          window.location = appleAppStoreLink;
     }, 100);
     window.location = url;
}
function launchWeb(url) {
    window.location = url;
}


$(function() {
     $('#my-link').click( function () { 
          var iOS = /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test( navigator.userAgent );
          var android =  /(Android)/g.test( navigator.userAgent );
          if(android) {
              //alert("tst");
              launchAndroidApp('http://www.example.com'); 
          }
          else if(iOS) {
              launchiOSApp('http://www.example.com');
          }
          else {
              launchWeb('http://www.example.com');
          }
     });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<a id="my-link" href = "#">web-link</a>
</body>
</html>
```